# License4J : Use product key on a different machine

Tags: licensing, license4j

I am using License4J license manager tool to generate licenses for my application. I have bought a product key using which I have installed this tool on my machine but now I would like to install it on some other machine and remove it from my machine.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Click on **Help** menu and **Licensing** menu item in License Manager GUI. Deactivate the license, then you can install and activate on another computer.